# If $A\subset\mathbb{N}$ with $\bar{d}(A)=1$ then $\bar{d}(A/d)=1$ for any positive integer $d$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

We want to prove that if $A\subset\mathbb{N}$ with $\bar{d}(A)=1$ then $\bar{d}(A/d)=1$ for any positive integer $d$, where $A/d := \{n : nd \in A\}$. According to the definition, we have that since $\bar{d}(A) = 1$, then we have $\limsup \frac{|A \cap [1,N]|}{N} = 1$. Then $$\bar{d} (A/d) = \limsup \frac{|(A/d) \cap [1,N]|}{N} = \limsup \frac{|\{n: nd \in A\}| \cap [1,N]}{N}$$But i don't know how to proceed from here. Could anyone help me please? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a hint:

For all $n$ we have

$$ \frac{|(A/d) \cap \{1,\ldots,n\}|}{n} = \frac{|A \cap \{d,2d,\ldots,nd\}|}{n} = \frac{| A \cap d \mathbf{N} \cap \{1,2,\ldots,nd\}|}{n} = d \frac{| A \cap d \mathbf{N} \cap \{1,2,\ldots,nd\}|}{nd},$$

Where $d \mathbf{N} = \{d,2d,3d,\ldots\}$. From this, we can show that $\overline{d}(A/d) = d \cdot \overline{d}(A \cap d \mathbf{N})$.

$d \mathbf{N}$ takes up $1/d^{\text{th}}$ of the space in $\mathbf{N}$, so, since $\overline{d}(A) = 1$, we should feel that $d \mathbf{N}$ ought to take up about $1/d^{\text{th}}$ of the space in $A$. In fact, for all $n$ we have

$$ \frac{|A \cap \{1,\ldots,n\}|}{n} = \frac{|(A \setminus d \mathbf{N}) \cap \{1,\ldots,n\}|}{n} + \frac{|A \cap d \mathbf{N}\cap \{1,\ldots,n\}|}{n} \leq \frac{d-1}{d} +  \frac{|A \cap d \mathbf{N}\cap \{1,\ldots,n\}|}{n}.$$

Using this observation along with the fact that $\overline{d}(A) = 1$, we can show that $\overline{d}(A \cap d \mathbf{N}) = 1/d$. Combined with our earlier work, we see that $\overline{d}(A/d) = 1$.

This is not a complete solution, but it is the right idea.